# Pic32MZ interrupt signal to output pin set without CPU usage

Tags: microcontroller, pic, interrupts

I generate ADC digital comparator interrupts. I want to use this interrupt to trigger Input Capture module. To achive precise timing it will be better to directly trigger IC module with ADC digital comparator interrupt. I couldn't find a solution to do this. If I can trigger GPIO pins or other modules with this interrupt to generate a signal on the output pins, this can be used as a IC input signal. I guess DMA can triggered and can be use with ADC digital comparator interrupt. But i can't use DMA module.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which Pic32MZ? Unless you specify, it's anyone's best guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a wild guess that you're using a DS60001320H-compatible "PIC32MZ Embedded Connectivity with Floating Point Unit (EF) Family" device.

Let's also make a wild guess that you're using one of the ADCCMPENx/ADCCMPCON1 comparator channels.

The input capture module explicitly only pays attention to a pin for capture events:

[image: input capture]

so one simple option is to route pin C1OUT (from one of the analog comparators, not an ADC digital comparator) to pin IC1. This has the advantage that you could add a test pad to probe timings.

Failing that you're stuck with software. At 252 MHz, a single interrupt-and-bitset should not cause too much delay.